# How to avoid getting referenced before assignment when sending list back to html page from flask app

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, tweepy

I am trying to get tweets using twitter api using a search word. The html form requests user to enter search word and the flask app gets it using request method and collects all the tweets from API. The problem is when i need to send tweets back to HTML page to print. I'm getting referenced before assignment error.
Heres my flask app.

```
@app.route('/realtime')
def realtime():
  tweetCount=0
  s=[]
  if request.method == 'POST':
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True,
               wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
    search = request.form.get('word')
    public_tweets = api.search(q=search, lang="te", count=100)
    for tweet in public_tweets:

                Tweet = tweet.text
                Tweet = re.sub('((www\.[\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))','URL',Tweet)
                Tweet = re.sub('@[^\s]+','TWITTER_USER',Tweet)
                Tweet = re.sub('[\s]+', ' ', Tweet)
                Tweet = re.sub(r'#([^\s]+)', r'\1', Tweet)
                Tweet = Tweet.strip('\'"')
                a = ':)'
                b = ':('
                Tweet = Tweet.replace(a,'')
                Tweet = Tweet.replace(b,'')
                tag = 'TWITTER_USER' 
                rt = 'RT'
                url = 'URL'
                Tweet = Tweet.replace(tag,'')
                tweetCount+=1
                if rt in Tweet:
                  continue
                Tweet = Tweet.replace(rt,'')
                Tweet = Tweet.replace(url,'')
                s.append(Tweet) 
  return render_template('home.html',
                          tweets=s)
```

Here is my html code with python blocks to print the tweets that we get from the app.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flask Tweepy Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form class="form-inline" method="GET" action="{{ url_for('realtime') }}">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="word">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        {% for tweet in tweets %}
        {{ tweet}}   
        {% endfor %}  
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any other way to send that tweets to html page without getting referenced before assignment.

Comment: you only set the list `s=['']` inside your if statment, yet you try to use it in your ode even if you dont go into the if. So when your request is not a POST. I.E a get you will try to return. `return render_template('home.html',tweets=s)`, but you have not set `s` hence the error referenced before assignment. you should move `s=['']` to sit before your if statment

Comment: Then I am getting empty list as output.

Comment: But what's your expected behaviour if the request methods is a GET instead of a POST

Comment: Is there anything else wrong in the code?? Would you mind checking it ?

Comment: Right now your code will only show tweets if the request method is a post. It sounds like your not actually doing a POST but instead doing a GET. your code doesn't cover that use case

Comment: Since I'm getting search word from html page, shouldn't it be a POST method??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215511/discussion-between-ganesh-chandra-and-chris-doyle).

Comment: Well I guess. Can you show your html code that submits the form

Comment: Read the problem description again, I have included html code too.

Comment: erm right here.....`<form class="form-inline" method="GET" action="{{ url_for('realtime') }}">`   you specifically set the method as GET........`method="GET"` thats why your server side code has an issue as it only handles POST

Comment: Thanks a ton man, it worked.